# How I parse Color java class to JSON with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, awt, json-deserialization

I am trying to deserialise the `Color` class from `JSON` with `Jackson` but it throws exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:
>   Unrecognized field "colorSpace" (class java.awt.Color), not marked as
>   ignorable.

What i'm doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
File act = new File(new File().getAbsolutePath());

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
File f = new File(act, "123.JSON");

om.writeValue(f, new person());
person per = om.readValue(f, person.class);
System.out.println(per);
```

This is my person class:

```
public class person implements Serializable {
    //it include getters, setters and builder

   String nombe = "Pepe";
   String CI = "12345678978";
   Color c = Color.red;
}
```

Comment: This looks like code that you can turn into a [mcve] with almost no additional work: could you please do that? (I.e. show the single-file code that people can copy and paste, and then run through javac without any additional work?)

Comment: Also show the JSON you're parsing.

Comment: The field called in the json most likely is called "colorSpace" whereas your field is called "c"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.awt.Color` class is not a regular `POJO` or `Enum`. You need to implement custom serialiser and deserialiser if you want to store it in `JSON` format. `Color` class can be represented by its `RGB` representation and you can store it as a number:

```
class ColorJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Color value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (value == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
            return;
        }
        gen.writeNumber(value.getRGB());
    }
}

class ColorJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public Color deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return new Color(p.getValueAsInt());
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule awtModule = new SimpleModule("AWT Module");
        awtModule.addSerializer(Color.class, new ColorJsonSerializer());
        awtModule.addDeserializer(Color.class, new ColorJsonDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(awtModule);

        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Person());
        System.out.println(json);

        System.out.println(mapper.readValue(json, Person.class));
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
{"nombe":"Pepe","c":-65536,"ci":"12345678978"}
Person{nombe='Pepe', CI='12345678978', c=java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]}
```

Take a look on similar question where `Color` is stored as `JSON` object:

- [Unable to deserialize java.awt.color using jackson deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070673/unable-to-deserialize-java-awt-color-using-jackson-deserializer)