# How to deserialize array of hex colors to awt.color with Jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I am fetching a JSON object from an API with includes:

```
"palette": ["#019701","#FE82B8","#FAFF04","#017FFF","#FD8141"],
```

I have pojo like:

```
public class PanelInfo {
//    ...
    private Color[] colorPalette;
//    ...
}
```

To deserialize I tried adding:

```
class ColorJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public Color deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
            
        return Color.decode(p.getValueAsString());
    }
}
```

and other variations of extracting from `p.getValueAsString()`.

No go. Everything I try returns:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.awt.Color` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('#221875')

It seems I am not working with the JsonParser correctly. Any ideas?

Update: Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/11713777/dariosicily This is working code:

```
public class PanelInfo {
...
@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = ColorJsonDeserializer.class)
public Color[] palette;
...
}
```

and deserializer class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import java.awt.Color; 
import java.io.IOException;


 public  class ColorJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Color> {

    @Override
    public Color deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        return new Color(Integer.parseUnsignedInt(p.getValueAsString().substring(1), 16));
    }

}
```

Note the substring to get rid of the leading #

Comment: Have you registered the deserializer with your object mapper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to deserialize java.awt.color using jackson deserializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42070673/unable-to-deserialize-java-awt-color-using-jackson-deserializer)

Comment: michael - yes, I did. Alex, what I used to help me write the deserializer but the issue is an array of color.

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your `palette` field with the [`JsonDeserialize`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html) annotation and the [`contentUsing`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html#contentUsing()) deserializer class because `palette` is a `Color` array and not a single value:

```
public class PanelInfo {

    @JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = ColorJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Color[] palette;
}
```

Comment: That is trick that I didnt know. Thanks.

Comment: @Scaddenp You are welcome.